# Discord.py - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was casually programming my Discord bot, and when I was done, I went and tested my code (which sends a welcoming message when someone joins the server) by using my alternative account to join the test server. But when the alternative joined, I got this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\quinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\GrindersValley\ValleysPy\cogs\Hellogoodbye.py", line 36, in on_member_join
    await client.get_channel(844229450928488458).send(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'\
```

I have no clue what's wrong. My code: https://pastebin.com/VntL0y5d

Comment: Are you certain that this channel exists and the bot has access to it?

Comment: The bot is in the same guild/server, and has all permissions in that guild. It should have access to in this case edit the name of the voice channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your issue is that your declaration of `client` and `bot` is inconsistent, so change all instances of `client` to `bot`.

Second, all calls upon `bot` inside the cog should be `self.bot` because you declared that in `_init_` as a class variable, so ex:
`bot.get_channel()` should be `self.bot.get_channel()`

Third, your cache may not be populated so add:

```
await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
```

to the beginning of your listeners to ensure your client's cache is fully populated before trying to call on it

Comment: This removes the error, but now the code doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: Two things, change all instances of "client" to "bot" since that's what you're calling most places, and anything using the bot object inside of the cog, i.e. bot.get_channel() needs to be self.bot instead of just bot (i.e. self.bot.get_channel()), since you declared that in `_init_`, hope this helps! (I'll edit my answer to include this)

Comment: Sorry for the late response Alyx, but I have replaced:
1) All clients to bot
2) Did self.bot.get_channel(channelid)
Now I get a different error:
AttributeError: 'Hellogoodbye' object has no attribute 'bot'

Comment: Found your issue!! Remove one underline from each side of `def __init__`, since you have it as `def ___init___` ! I tested it and it should work now, if you have more issues, I'm happy to give a pastebin of the code i got to work!

Comment: Awesome!! Are you okay with marking my answer as accepted if it's all working now?

Comment: New to SOV, so how do I do this?

Comment: Theres a checkmark under the up/down votes, if you click that, itll accept mine!

Answer (score 0):

TextChannel wasn't found. If the bot can't fetch the channel from its cache then it returns None, which is what's triggering your error.